# find certain string , broke the row and create a new row/rows

Tags: python, pandas, string

Hi i have string which i need to find certain strings and create a new rows within the data frame
ex: data - find "Number of days" and create new row same as "Appx. average wt"

```
data = {'Name': ['112 13 15 195 46 60 7 28 88 73 16 91 9  Number of days 32 30 29 32 30 30 31 32 31 29 30 31 30  Appx. average wt 39 4 40 74 331 302 273 263 277 274 307 295 303']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data) 
data_out = {'Name': ['112 13 15 195 46 60 7 28 88 73 16 91 9',  'Number of days 32 30 29 32 30 30 31 32 31 29 30 31 30',  'Appx. average wt 39 4 40 74 331 302 273 263 277 274 307 295 303']}
data_out = pd.DataFrame(data_out)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as follows:

- Use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with a regex pattern and set `expand` to `True` to get the result in separate columns. The regex used below checks for one or more whitespaces (`\s+`), followed by a uppercase letter (`A-Z`).
- Now, use [`.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) to transpose the result, turning the columns into rows.
- Finally, use [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to rename the one column that we end up with (it's name will be `0`).

```
res = data.Name.str.split(r'\s+(?=[A-Z])', expand=True, regex=True).T\
    .rename(columns={0:'Name'})
print(res)

                                                Name
0             112 13 15 195 46 60 7 28 88 73 16 91 9
1  Number of days 32 30 29 32 30 30 31 32 31 29 3...
2  Appx. average wt 39 4 40 74 331 302 273 263 27...
```